# Error when importing urllib

Tags: python, urllib, python-3.6

When I import urllib.request in python 3, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllibExample.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request
  File "/home/andrew/Python/urllib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not 
a package
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error message since urllib.request is in the standard library. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: try `urllib2` maybe?

Comment: Which framework and version of python do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a file of your own named `urllib.py`. The import is being attempted from this file instead of the system installed one.

Rename your file.

Comment: That worked! Thank you.